# Can't query old rows in column after changing type from BINARY to VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I changed data type on a column from VARCHAR to BINARY to VARCHAR again. Now it returns no results on that column for old rows, but still returns results on new rows. It returned results for all rows before. Why does this happen?

Query example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = :column
```

Comment: May be because you've modified (broken) your data?

Comment: I didn't do anything to the data more than changing data type. Shouldn't the data type of the stored data also change?

Comment: Well, we have no idea what you've done and what happened. What we certainly know - is that the data has changed.

Comment: It's still the same content in the column and it looks the same with the eye. Just changed data type on the column.

Comment: If mysql does not match it - it's different (even if it visually looks the same). Mysql is not intended to annoy you intentionally.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to restore the data?

Comment: @embe, if you have a daily backup you can find some great tutorials on how to restore your data by Googling "MySQL Restore Backup."

Comment: @jbarker2160 - Doesn't have any backups. :( Maybe it's possible to write a script to read the data and then set it back again. It's only if the column is in the WHERE clause as it's not working. (think it's possible with php, is it possible with just sql?)

Comment: "read the data and then set it back again" --- if data is already broken, then it's too late to do that